# Как правильно образовывать отчества от мужских имён, оканчивающихся на -ий?

Tags: буквы

Если конкретно, то интересует имя Аполлинарий. Но вообще хотелось бы узнать, есть ли общий алгоритм. Согласно советским словарям, пишут и так и этак, например: Геннадий — Геннадьевич/Геннадьевна, Геннадиевич/Геннадиевна. То есть то с мягким знаком, то с буквой И. Хотелось бы разобраться, есть ли здесь нормы и законы или же, может быть, каждый волен писать по-своему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Грамматический словарь" Зализняка дает при имени **Аполлинарий** помету §26 (//), что означает, что верны оба варианта, а вариант Аполлинариевич носит более официальный характер.

[https://gramdict.ru/search/Аполлинарий](https://gramdict.ru/search/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

> § 26. Образец: **Васи́лий** мо 7а, § 26. Ссылка на настоящий параграф указывает на то, что от данного имени отчества образуются по модели: **Васи́льевич, Васи́льевна** (т. е. с заменой и на ь перед -евич, -евна). Многие имена имеют помету «§ 26 (//)», указывающую на то, что данная особенность у них факультативна, например: **Арка́дий** мо 7а, § 26 (//). Это значит, что отчества здесь имеют вид **Арка́дьевич** и **Арка́диевич**, **Арка́дьевна** и **Арка́диевна**. Вариант с **ь** в этих случаях носит более бытовой, вариант с **и** — более официальный характер.

https://gramdict.ru/names#para26

Answer (score 2):

In Russia, when you get the birth certificate for your baby in the registry office or in the hospital, they would give you a piece of paper and ask to write down the baby's name and patronymic.

If the baby's father's name ends in *-ий*, you can write it down both ways, using *-иевич/-иевна* or *-ьевич/-ьевна*, and they would just copy what you had written for them.  They are happy to use whatever spelling you give them, as long as it's remotely resembling the father's name used in the birth certificate.

Same holds for names like *Меланья/Мелания, Наталья/Наталия* etc.

These days, the conventional way of spelling such names is using the soft sign (*-ьевич/-ьевна*), except for names with consonant clusters like *Дмитриевич, Мотриевич* etc.

Using the non-conventional spelling in the birth certificate is likely to cause trouble in the future, if the name is mentioned in other documents with different spelling.

Banks and other commercial institutions usually account for the discrepancies like this in their rule guides. If your patronymic is, say, *Геннадиевич* and you are in for a money transfer addressed to a *Геннадьевич*, or the other way around, you're likely to get the money.

Wills, court rulings and other legal stuff is harder. Same as with *е/ё*, the discrepancies like that may and will cause problems.